# Implemetation of a scroll view in a Navigation view

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, android-navigationview

I have created a DrawerLayout with a NavigationView. The navigationView is defined like this in the xml file :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_main"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavigationDrawerStyle"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <include layout="@layout/menu_item_main" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Instead of defining app:menu ----, I had defined a seperate layout and it worked good till the number of items in list was small. Once it was more , I added a scrollable layout inside the menu_item_main, tried covering the NavigationView inside a scrollView. Nothing seems to work for me.

I know using a menu screen would solve the problem, but the logic of the app depends on the layout presence and can't change it. Does anyone have any idea of how to make the menu items in the list scrollable without using app:menu ?

The menu layout file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_height"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/home_unselected" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/home_item_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_medium" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_identify"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nav_identify_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/closure_unselected" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/identify_item_text"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_medium" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add menu layout file to the question?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira : I've added the menu layout.

Comment: I dont see you scrollview you removed?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira : The whole linear layout was inside a scrollview, but it didn't cause any difference. So, it's removed in the question.

Comment: I figured out the best way would be to replace the   <include layout="@layout/menu_item_main" /> by a menu. That had scroll functionality pre-implemented in it, which caused lesser headache!